# Flutter String Replace

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to match and replace that come from api.
Here is example data that will come from api.

```
String data;
```

150k or L005K, or K005

I want to replace :
L150K to 1500
L005K to 5000
K005 to 0005
`Text(${items.data})`
If item.data is L150K i want to replace it with 1500,
else if item.data is L005K => 5000

Comment: Please explain your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check it in `switch` - `case`:

```
String result = '';
switch(items.data) {
  case 'L150K':
    result = '1500';
    break;
  case 'L005K':
    result = '5000';
    break;
  case 'K005':
    result = '0005';
    break;
}
/* todo something ... */
Text(result);
```

Comment: String _switchText(data){ switch(data) { case 'L150K': return '1500'; break; case 'L005K': return '5000'; break; case 'K005': return '0005'; break; } } // then Text("data:$switchText(item.data)");